# How to fix onClickListener

Tags: android, methods, onclicklistener, virtual, invoke

I have this code the MainActivity and activity_main.

The problem is with the the android monitor says that I  Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void  on a null object reference. I tried everything but I can't fix it. Hope someone can help me!

1.main_activity

https://pastebin.com/2D8sjzAp

2. MainActivity

https://pastebin.com/dmQZwu3R

```
private static final char ADDITION = '+';
private static final char SUBTRACTION = '-';
private static final char MULTIPLICATION = '*';
private static final char DIVISION = '/';

private char CURRENT_ACTION;

private double valueOne = Double.NaN;
private double valueTwo;

private DecimalFormat decimalFormat;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("#.##########");

    Button buttonDot = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonDot);
    Button buttonZero = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonZero);
    Button buttonOne = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonOne);
    Button buttonTwo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonTwo);
    Button buttonThree = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonThree);
    Button buttonFour = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonFour);
    Button buttonFive = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonFive);
    Button buttonSix = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSix);
    Button buttonSeven = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSeven);
    Button buttonEight = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonEight);
    Button buttonNine = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonNine);
    Button buttonAdd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonAdd);
    Button buttonSubtract = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSubtract);
    Button buttonMultiply = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonMultiply);
    Button buttonDivide = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonDivide);
    Button buttonClear = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonClear);
    Button buttonEqual = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonEqual);

    final EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    final TextView infoTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.infoTextView);

    buttonDot.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            editText.setText(editText.getText() + ".");
        }
    });

    buttonZero.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            editText.setText(editText.getText() + "0");
        }
    });

    buttonOne.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
           editText.setText(editText.getText() + "1");
        }
    });

    buttonTwo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            editText.setText(editText.getText() + "2");
        }
    });

    buttonThree.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            editText.setText(editText.getText() + "3");
        }
    });

    buttonFour.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            editText.setText(editText.getText() + "4");
        }
    });

    buttonFive.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            editText.setText(editText.getText() + "5");
        }
    });

    buttonSix.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            editText.setText(editText.getText() + "6");
        }
    });

    buttonSeven.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            editText.setText(editText.getText() + "7");
        }
    });

    buttonEight.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            editText.setText(editText.getText() + "8");
        }
    });

    buttonNine.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            editText.setText(editText.getText() + "9");
        }
    });

    buttonAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            computeCalculation();
            CURRENT_ACTION = ADDITION;
            infoTextView.setText(decimalFormat.format(valueOne) + "+");
            editText.setText(null);
        }
    });

   buttonSubtract.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            computeCalculation();
            CURRENT_ACTION = SUBTRACTION;
           infoTextView.setText(decimalFormat.format(valueOne) + "-");
            editText.setText(null);
        }
    });

   buttonMultiply.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            computeCalculation();
            CURRENT_ACTION = MULTIPLICATION;
            infoTextView.setText(decimalFormat.format(valueOne) + "*");
            editText.setText(null);
        }
    });

    buttonDivide.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            computeCalculation();
            CURRENT_ACTION = DIVISION;
            infoTextView.setText(decimalFormat.format(valueOne) + "/");
            editText.setText(null);
        }
    });

    buttonEqual.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            computeCalculation();
           infoTextView.setText(infoTextView.getText().toString() +
                    decimalFormat.format(valueTwo) + " = " + decimalFormat.format(valueOne));
            valueOne = Double.NaN;
            CURRENT_ACTION = '0';
        }
    });

    buttonClear.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if(editText.getText().length() > 0) {
                CharSequence currentText = editText.getText();
               editText.setText(currentText.subSequence(0, currentText.length()-1));
            }
            else {
                valueOne = Double.NaN;
                valueTwo = Double.NaN;
                editText.setText("");
                infoTextView.setText("");
            }
        }
    });
}

private void computeCalculation() {
    if(!Double.isNaN(valueOne)) {
        EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        valueTwo = Double.parseDouble(editText.getText().toString());
        editText.setText(null);

        if(CURRENT_ACTION == ADDITION)
            valueOne = this.valueOne + valueTwo;
        else if(CURRENT_ACTION == SUBTRACTION)
            valueOne = this.valueOne - valueTwo;
        else if(CURRENT_ACTION == MULTIPLICATION)
            valueOne = this.valueOne * valueTwo;
        else if(CURRENT_ACTION == DIVISION)
            valueOne = this.valueOne / valueTwo;
    }
    else {
        try {
            EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);//potential
            valueOne = Double.parseDouble(editText.getText().toString());
        }
        catch (Exception e){}
    }


}
private void showIn2(){
    EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    valueTwo = Double.parseDouble(editText.getText().toString());

    editText.setText(null);



    editText.setText(Integer.toString((int) valueTwo,2));



}
```

}

Comment: well it looks that one of your ids is not found in your view, so double check your ID names

Comment: From Review: Please try to isolate your issue in a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and post only the relevant part of the source code. Do not  post source code using links, they will get broken someday and you question will then become useless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this line in `OnCreate()`

```
 setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

Answer (score 1):

In Android environment, There are two basic building blocks for an activity:

- XML layout (user facing screen)
- Corresponding backend code (written in `Java` or `Kotlin`)

First main thing you have to do when creating an activity is to link your XML file to the corresponding Java or `Kotlin` code (Android studio will do this for you when creating an activity)

So you should include the below line of code in your `onCreate()` method to link the XML file:

`setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);`

Your `onCreate()` method should look like this :

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    // your code goes here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the layout view before binding views;

```
Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.your_XML_file);//This is the line you are missing
```